# How to expose classes in subdirectory to scripts in parent directory

Tags: python, package

I am trying to create a python3 package looks like this:

```
    mypackage/
      models/
        __init__.py
        model_a.py
          class ModelA
        model_b.py
      train.py
```

Within `train.py` I would like to import `ModelA` like `from models import ModelA` ,

rather than using `from models.model_a import ModelA`.

Is this possible? Many thanks.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari: His question was to expose `ModelA` class directly, rather than using the absolute module.

Comment: Hello @Kris my bad, I didn't read properly thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Any way, I edited it to look a little better :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding the line

```
from models.model_a import ModelA
```

in the file `mypackage/models/__init__.py`

After doing this, you can import it like

```
from models import ModelA
```